# Power BI data refresh timeout

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-server, timeout, refresh-rate, microsoft-powerbi

So I have built some dashboards in Power BI that have direct linked data to my access queries that are connected to sql servers. when I refresh them individually they work fine just take some time. when I go to refresh all they take a couple minutes and time out and this is preventing me from setting up the gateway and scheduled refresh. is there a way for me to extend timeout length on the access data refresh? thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you mean you have Power BI linked to Microsoft Access, which is linked to SQL Server?

Comment: correct. the queries are direct linked through access

Answer (score 1):

That seems a redundant architecture which may be the root cause of your timeouts.  I would always connect Power BI directly to SQL Server.

In the Query steps, move your Filter, Group By or Remove Duplicate steps as early as you can. They are usually translated to SQL (e.g. Filter => WHERE criteria) and run on the SQL Server to minimize network traffic.

If you still get timeouts, right-click on a Query Step and choose **View Native Query** to get the generated SQL (where available). Pass this to your SQL dba and ask them to tune Indexes etc to help it.